# Eclipse moonrise dark theme doesn't let me see the first suggestion

Tags: eclipse

I really need dark themes when programming, so I installed Moonrise in Eclipse (Preferences > Appearance > Theme > MoonRise), and everything is kind of OK, except for a few details.

The most important is this one:
I can't see the first proposal in suggestions, because it is beneath a gray block:

[image: eclipse moonrise first suggestion grayed out]

The second problem, less important, is this:

[image: Perspective moonrise problem]

It is hard for me to see the name of the non active perspectives (in this case DDMS).

How can I solve these problems?

I'm using Windows 7, with the "Windows Classic" theme

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart Eclipse? It sometimes tends to do that. Or even start Eclipse with `-clean`.

I would try using `Classic`, and not `Windows Classic`.

I also recommend you took a look at [jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes). I'm using a dark one from there, and it's perfect. I had no major visual problems once my eyes got used to it.

Comment: Yes I restarted several times and tried Moonrise Standalone too... it just won't work, and its weird because before formatting my computer I also had Eclipse/Moonrise and I don't remember having this problem. Regarding your Windows 7 theme suggestion: I couldn't find "Classic", just "Windows Classic". Regarding jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes, I tried that too but.. I have to manually set all colors? Aren't there any presets?

Comment: @sports Actually those are Eclipse themes, not editor themes. This was my bad. [Just pick another one from here, maybe you'll get lucky :-)](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/)